# Dev-C++ isn't writing output file to disk

Tags: c, linux, file, file-io, dev-c++

When I run my program on linux at uni the program works fine. The `fred.out` file is created. But when I run it at home on Dev-C++ it does not write an output file.

How do I fix this? I have been searching and trying for a couple of hours now. I have tried including multiple libraries. Could this be a security issue?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp_1;
    float mat[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int i,j;

    fp_1 = fopen("fred.out","w");
    for (j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            fprintf(fp_1," %+10.2f\n",mat[j][i]);
        fprintf(fp_1,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp_1);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT:

[image: after entering a fopen() check]

Comment: I edited my answer to post an example of how to check errno.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the success of `fopen()` before using the returned pointer. Otherwise, if `fopen()` fails (to open the file), using the returned `FILE *` further will be [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Additionally, upon `fopen()` failure, you can check the `errno` to decide the reson behind the failure.

Comment: Thank you! I have added this fopen() check and it has failed. what should I do?

Comment: @ThomasM I told...check `errno` for the reson behind the failure.

Comment: how do i check errno?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and mingw, you may need to open the file in binary mode, adding a "b" to the fopen mode:

```
fp_1 = fopen("fred.out","wb");
```

Edit2: As Degustaf said in comments, you can use `char * strerror(int errnum)`, including errno.h and string.h, to know what was the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp_1;
    float mat[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int i,j;

    fp_1 = fopen("fred.out","w");
    if(fp_1 == NULL) {
        printf("\n%s",strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    for (j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            fprintf(fp_1," %+10.2f\n",mat[j][i]);
        fprintf(fp_1,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp_1);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: You can check errno by the following way, including errno.h, and checking for the variable named "errno". In the following example, there are some errors not listed, because fopen can set errno to the same errors than malloc, see man pages of fopen, open, and malloc for more details:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void func_errno() {

  switch(errno) {

    case EACCES: printf("\nEACCES"); break;
    case EEXIST: printf("\nEEXIST"); break;
    case EFAULT: printf("\nEFAULT"); break;
    case EFBIG: printf("\nEFBIG"); break;
    case EINTR: printf("\nEINTR"); break;
    case EISDIR: printf("\nEISDIR"); break;
    case ELOOP: printf("\nELOOP"); break;
    case EMFILE: printf("\nEMFILE"); break;
    case ENAMETOOLONG: printf("\nENAMETOOLONG"); break;
    case ENFILE: printf("\nENFILE"); break;
    case ENODEV: printf("\nENODEV"); break;
    case ENOENT: printf("\nENOENT"); break;
    case ENOMEM: printf("\nENOMEM"); break;
    case ENOSPC: printf("\nENOSPC"); break;
    case ENOTDIR: printf("\nENOTDIR"); break;
    case ENXIO: printf("\nENXIO"); break;
    case EOVERFLOW: printf("\nEOVERFLOW"); break;
    case EPERM: printf("\nEPERM"); break;
    case EROFS: printf("\nEROFS"); break;
    case EWOULDBLOCK: printf("\nEWOULDBLOCK"); break;
    default: printf("\nOther error."); break;
  }
}


int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp_1;
    float mat[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int i,j;

    fp_1 = fopen("fred.out","w");
    if(fp_1 == NULL) {
        func_errno();
        return 1;
    }

    for (j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            fprintf(fp_1," %+10.2f\n",mat[j][i]);
        fprintf(fp_1,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp_1);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: replacing "wb" with "w" did not change the outcome, thankd for your help though = )

Comment: `func_errno` is a bad re-implementation of an already available function, [strerror](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was wrong but I copied my files from my thumb-disk to my hard-drive and it had no problem writing files. Thanks for all your answers guys!